# How to compare sym variable from vpa in matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, arbitrary-precision

Assume that I have two variables with 300 digits of precision:

```
a = vpa(sqrt(2),300);
b = vpa(sqrt(3),300);
```

I want to know whether `(b-a) > (1e-15)` is true or false. What should I do?

Comment: Cant check, but in fact `(b-a)>(1e-15)` appears to be valid syntax. Do you get an error and if so which one (and have you looked for solutions regarding this error)?

Comment: I got this error :
??? Function 'gt' is not defined for values of class 'sym'.

Comment: I think that you're using an older version of Matlab and the Symbolic Math toolbox as this works fine in R2012b+. What happens if you use `c = vpa(1e-15,300)` or just `c = sym(1e-15)`? Do you have the `isAlways` function in your version?

Comment: thanks horchler. Using matlab R2013a, everything fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply looking for this:

```
double(b-a)>(1e-15)
```

Comment: how if I want to use all the 300 digits?

Comment: @zee I am not sure if I understand the problem, but perhaps you want to substract the 1e-15 before the casting as double and then compare with 0.

Comment: I wanto to avoid the roundoff error from double()...is it possible to use all the 300 digits for comparison?

Comment: @zee as I said before, you should first substract. `double(b-a-1e15)>0` or `double(b-a-vpa(1e-15,300))>0` should do the trick and is NOT prone to the roundoff arrors you seem to worry about.

Comment: thanks dennis for all of your comment...
but i think `(b-a-1e15)` didn't use 300 digits...